# how to access my master page value in my child page .aspx page

Tags: asp.net

in master page  i hvae this  code here  i am able  to get the value in 
  **Staffname**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server" />
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      //  attach to the pageLoaded event
                Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);        

 function pageLoaded(sender, args) 
{
  var Staffname='<%= obj.ClientID %>'; 
  // this i am getting from code  behind .i am  able  to get the value                

}
  </script>
```

on how every page load this  function  executes

So now  from my master page i need to access this value in .aspx page
 is there any way i can do it

anyhelp  would be great

thank you

Answer (score 2):

To access your master page you need to insert a link to it on the child page:

```
<%@ MasterType TypeName="YourMasterPage" %>
```

You can then access it by exposing public properties in your Master page and then just referencing the Master by:

```
string someValue = Master.YourControlProperty;
// or
int someIntValue = Master.GetSomeIntValue();
```

Comment: This would work as well, but it still requires the Page to set the javascript, ideally the MasterPage should be setting the javascript as this is where it actually exists

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do this by having the Page inherit from an Interface which contains the property that you want to set.  Then cast the "Page" property to this interface (maybe put a check in there to make sure it is that type).

In the MasterPage:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IMyPage page = Page as IMyPage
    if(page != null)
    {
        //use page.MyProperty
    }
}
```

In the Page's code behind

```
public class MyPage : Page, IMyPage
{
    // From the interface IMyPage
    public string MyProperty { get { return MyTextBox.ClientID; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your child page class (assuming it will only ever have one type of Master page called, say, "MPClass", and assuming the property on the Master Page is called "YourProperty", you'd do:

```
var myPropertyFromMasterPageInChild = ((MPClass)Master).YourProperty;
```

Comment: This would work as well - just relies on the Page setting that ClientId in the javascript, rather than the MasterPage (which is where it resides)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [MasterType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx) directive in your content page.